# How to extract the random shift intensity difference a 3D array elements in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

I am doing image segmentation on 3D medical images. In one of the related papers, authors have extracted a feature that I do not understand how should I calculate it,  `f(x, u) = I(x + u) − I(x)` is the random shift intensity difference between voxel `x` and the offset `u` in `mm^3`. If we consider that the pixel_spacing of the medical image is `0.36x0.36x0.7 mm^3`, how I can extract and obtain this feature for the whole volume in an memory and computationally efficient way for `u=2 mm^3`? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `u` should probably be a displacement vector, rather than a scalar value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment by @user630317 points out, for a 3D image, u should be a 3D vector.

Also, the image is 'voxelized' i,e, discrete.
Therefore x is a vector with integer entries and units as voxels (not mm).
Elements of u may or may not be an integer but has units as voxels.
If u has fractional elements than would would have to do interpolate the fractional shifts and would lose information.

The matlab function imtranslate can do both integer and fractional shifts.

Let, I be an 3-D-array in matlab representing the 3D volume.
Let, u be a 3D vector of translations (in units of voxels).

Then the translated image would be I2 = imtranslate(I,u)

This is an example code with a 3D array:

```
I = randn(3,3,3);
u = [1.5,1,1];
I2 = imtranslate(I,u);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is exactly what I wanted. Is it correct if I define a shift range and then randomly choose a number within the shift range as the elements of `u`? For example a range `shift_range=[-3,3]` and 
`u = [randi(shift_range),randi(shift_range),randi(shift_range)];`